# Getting draws from a fitted distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I refered to [Fitting empirical distribution to theoretical ones with Scipy (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python?lq=1) and generated the best fit distribution to my sample data. I wish to generate random numbers according to the best fit distribution. See image below.

[image]

However, in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.f.html#numpy.random.f, there is only 3 parameters, dfnum, dfden, size=None, where should I insert `loc` and `scale`. By the way, the dnd and dfd in best fit distribution are float and in numpy.random, it wants integer.

If I use only dnd and dfd in the code `df_members['bd'] = df_members.bd.apply(lambda x: np.rint((np.random.f(dfnum=1441, dfden=19))) if x==-999 else x )` ,such values will be generated, which is false.

[image]

Comment: The F distribution only has two parameters. You should show the code for the fit to see exactly what are you fitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate use from the `scipy.stats` module the `f` distribution and ask random values from it given the parameters you already found using the `f.rvs` method which accepts the four parameters plus the size (number of draws you want).

```
from scipy.stats import f
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = f.rvs(1441.41, 19.1, -0.24, 26.5, 100000)
```

`values` is a 100000 length array with draws from the given distribution. You can see it as follows

```
plt.hist(values, bins=25)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mind show me the code which the random number can be generated from `scipy.stats` ?

Comment: I am trying to assign those random values into dataframe. `df_members['bd'] = df_members.bd.apply(lambda x: int(st.johnsonsu(a=-3.75,b=1.78, loc=11.36, scale=3.79)) if x==-999 else x )`, I am trying to round it into integer, any idea?

Comment: That's another question, better open a new one and not mix two different problems.

Comment: But what you should do is (at least what I'd try) is to get the length and positions of -999 cases in your `bd` column and then create an array of random values casting the type to in with the `astype` method and then go through the positions (indexes) and setting the new value.

Comment: @MervynLee basically the step you're asking extra is already answered in one of your previous questionhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/46938085/generate-different-random-numbers-to-multiple-rows-in-a-column in a better fashion than what I could have done

Comment: yep I solved it few minutes after I ask you. Thanks for the help anyway!